# How to dynamically add array values into string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with db col names.

```
$db_cols = ['name', 'age', 'gender'];
```

I need to add POST values into db query from array `$db_cols` dynamically. Result must be something like this.

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO tbl (id, '.implode(', ', $db_cols).', order) VALUES (?, '.str_repeat('?, ', count($db_cols)).' ?)', [$_POST['id'],$_POST['name'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['gender'], $order]);
```

But I need modify this part of the code above `$_POST['name'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['gender']`

Query result:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id, name, age, gender, order) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?),[1, 'Joe', '35', 'male', 1]
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Did my post helped you?